# MPI INT Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I'm creating a program that utilities MPI to determine the dotproduct of large matrices. I am having trouble determining how to send and receive the data through MPI_Send & MPI_Recv.

I have an array `int* vector` of size `nrc` that I would like to send and receive

```
MPI_Send(vector,nrc,MPI_INT,MASTER,123,MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
MPI_Recv(vector, nrc, MPI_INT, i, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

I'm running a test of nrc=4, where Master is receiving vectors from 3 slaves. However the results are garbage.

```
vector [ 255992420  255992420  255992420  255992420 ]
vector [ -260683762  -260683762  -260683762  -260683762 ]
vector [ 2018561464  2018561464  2018561464  2018561464 ]
```

Comment: nothing obviously wrong so far, can you edit your post and add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it wasn't in the send recv functions, they work as intended.

The problem was in the matrix init function that populates the matricies.

Originally I had these init functions inside of the `if id==master` and `if id==slave` blocks, which set the id to 0,1,2 etc.

When I moved them out of the master slave blocks the id no longer was 0,1,2, it was garbage. So when initializing the matrices using the id, they became garbage as well.